# Show that if $\frac{S_n - m_n}{s_n} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ with $X_k \sim \text{Ber}(p_k)$ then $\sum_k p_k(1-p_k) = +\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables, $X_k \sim \text{Ber}(p_k) \ \forall k \ge 1$. Set $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k, m_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n p_k, s_n^2 = \sum_{k = 1}^n p_k(1-p_k)$. Show that
$$
      \dfrac{S_n -m_n}{s_n} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} p_k(1-p_k) = +\infty
$$

I'm able to show the $\Leftarrow$ direction by checking the Linderberg conditions. However, I'm getting stuck at the $\Rightarrow$ direction, and I don't know any possible directions to show this, so any hints are appreciated, thank you.

**Update:** The Lindeberg conditions that I'm using is in Allan Gut's "Probability: A Graduate Course" book. In this book, the author state the following Lindeberg-Levy-Feller theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be independent random variables with finite variances, and set, for $k \ge 1, \mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mu_k, \text{Var}(X_k) = \sigma_k^2$ and, for $n \ge 1$, $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k, s_n^2 = \sum_{k = 1}^n \sigma_k^2$. The Lindeberg conditions requires:
> $$
>      L_1(n) = \max_{1 \le k \le n} \dfrac{\sigma_k^2}{s_n^2} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty \tag{1}
> $$
> and
> $$
>      L_2(n) = \dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[\vert X_k - \mu_k \vert^2 1\{\vert X_k - \mu_k \vert > \epsilon s_n\}] \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty\tag2
> $$
> Then:
> (i) If $(2)$ is satisfied, then so is $(1)$ and
> $$
>         \dfrac{1}{s_n}\sum_{k = 1}^n (X_k - \mu_k) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \tag3
> $$
> (ii) If $(1)$ and $(3)$ are satisfied, so is $(2)$.

Comment: Lindeberg is equivalent to asymptotic normality here if $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}p_k(1-p_k)/s_n^2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Have you tried that direction?

Comment: @Galton see the update on my question. I haven't seen the connection yet. If we already know $\max_{1 \le k \le n} p_k(1 - p_k)/s_n^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, does that ready implies $s_n^2 \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: Good question indeed. See that if $Var(S_{n}-S_{m})\xrightarrow{n,m\to\infty}0$ and thus $S_{n}-m_{n}$ would be $L^{2}$ Cauchy sequence (Martingale) if $s_{n}^{2}$ is bounded. Thus you are looking at $L^{2}$ convergence. Perhaps this will be of help but as of now I don't see how. Also, Lindeberg's condition is not a condition that is easy to verify so maybe you can add how you verified it in your question body.

Comment: In any case, to show the backward direction, it is easier to verify Liapunov's condition. i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{E(X_{k}-p_{k})^{4}}{s_{n}^{4}}\leq \frac{2s_{n}^{2}}{s_{n}^{4}}$ which goes to $0$ if $s_{n}\to\infty$ and thus Liapunov and hence Lindeberg's condition holds too.

Comment: Additionally, notice that if $\sup_{n}s_{n}^{2}<\infty$ and if $m_{n}$ also converges, then as  $S_{n}-m_{n}$ is an $L^{2}$ cauchy martingale, it converges almost surely also. So infact $S_{n}-m_{n}$ converges almost surely to some $X_{\infty}$ say and hence $S_{n}$ converges almost surely to $X_{\infty}+\lim_{n\to\infty}m_{n}$. Hence this limit $X_{\infty}+\lim_{n\to\infty}m_{n}$ will almost surely be an integer valued random variable (due to Borel Cantelli lemma) which is impossible if $X_{\infty}$ was a normal variate. So that leaves only the case when $m_{n}\to\infty$.

Comment: I think @DavideGiraudo is the go to expert in these types of problems. Maybe he'll se this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose not. Then $s_n\to s$ for some $s$ and $Z_n := \sum_{k=1}^n(X_k - p_k) \leadsto N(0, s^2)$. Let $Z_{-1,n} = \sum_{k=2}^n(X_k - p_k)$ so that $(X_1 - p_1) + Z_{-1,n} \leadsto N(0, s^2)$. Because $Z_{-1,n}$ must converge in distribution to some $Z_{-1}$ and, independently, $X_1 - p_1$ converges in distribution to $X_1 - p_1$, we have that $(X_1 - p_1) + Z_{-1}$ is normal. By Cramer's decomposition theorem, these two variables must be normal. This contradicts that $X_1$ is Bernoulli.

Comment: Ah finally. Completely forgot about the og Cramer decomposition. (+1). Although this might be a missile to kill a fly. I think there has to be some way to rescue my $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}-m_{n}$ being a random variable which takes values in a discrete set $\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ with positive probability argument. Let's see.

Comment: @Galton Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the book I'm using doesn't mention about the Cramer's decomposition theorem so I think it is weird for the author to use this theorem in the exercises. But if there aren't any new answers, I may accept yours

Comment: I'm not surprised, that result is a bit out there. An alternative would be showing that the characteristic function of $Z_n$ is not $e^{-(ts)^2/2}$ in the limit. This would be similar to the standard necessity proof of the Lindeberg condition but I would expect it to be quite laborious because it should boil down to some tricky case comparisons as in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

First see that if $s_{n}^{2}$ converges, then as I said in the comments, $$||S_{n}-m_{n}-S_{k}+m_{k}||_{L^{2}}^{2}=Var(S_{n}-S_{k})=|s_{n}^{2}-s_{k}^{2}|$$ which tends to $0$ as $n,k$ tend to infinity as $s_{n}^{2}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Hence $S_{n}-m_{n}$ is an $L^{2}$ Cauchy sequence and hence converges in L^{2} as well as almost surely. (If you don't understand this jump, then take it as a fact that for sums of independent variates, being cauchy in probability is equivalent to being cauchy almost surely due to a theorem by Levy). Otherwise, just consider a subsequence (which I do not relabel) $S_{n}-m_{n}$ along which you have almost sure convergence. And let $S_{n}-m_{n}\to X$, a random variable.

**Now consider the case that $m_{n}$ is convergent also (say to $m$).**

Then $S_{n}-m_{n}\to X\implies S_{n}\to X+m$ . But, as $m_{n}$ converges, by Borel Cantelli lemma, only finitely many $X_{k}$'s will be $1$ almost surely.

Thus almost surely $X+m$ will be an integer valued random variable. Now this is not possible if $X$ was a Normal variate (i.e. if $X$ was $N(0,\lim_{n\to\infty} s_{n}^{2})$ distributed.

**Now the only subcase is when $s_{n}^{2}$ converges but $m_{n}$ does not** . I think an elementary real analysis argument will yield that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}-m_{n}$ is almost surely discrete valued random variable and hence the limit cannot possibly be Gaussian. But embarrasingly, I am currently unable to prove it. Perhaps later when my brain frees up, I'll post an update. Meanwhile, I would encourage comments and discussions of my answer. It should go something like this though. The set of values of $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}-m_{n}$ should be almost surely contained in $D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}F_{n}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$

where $F_{k}$ is the possible set of values $S_{k}-m_{k}$ can take (and $F_{k}$ has cardinality $2^{k}$). So almost surely, the limiting variate should take values in $D$ which is not possible as for a normal distribution $\mathbb{P}_{N}$, we must have $\mathbb{P}_{N}(D)=0$ because $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}F_{n}$ is countable and hence $\mathbb{P}_{N}(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}F_{n})=0$ and $\mathbb{P}_{N}(\{\pm\infty\})=0$. So the limit cannot possibly be Normally distributed.

As for the other direction, as I said in the comments, it is often better and wiser to try and show Liapunov's condition as Lindeberg's condition is not one which is easy to verify.

To do that just notice that $E\bigg((X_{k}-p_{k})^{4}\bigg)=p_{k}(1-p_{k})^{4} + (1-p_{k})p_{k}^{4})\leq 2\cdot p_{k}(1-p_{k})$

Thus $$\frac{1}{s_{n}^{4}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E\bigg((X_{k}-p_{k})^{4}\bigg)\leq \frac{s_{n}^{2}}{s_{n}^{4}}\to 0$$ if $s_{n}^{2}\to\infty$ which verifies Liapunov's criteria as hence also verifies Lindeberg's condition.